# SMS Gateway Hardware/Software

Tags: linux, hardware, gateway, sms, sms-gateway

What would be the best hardware and software to set up a Linux-based SMS gateway using a Sprint texting plan?

Answer (score 2):

Look onto Kannel: http://www.kannel.org/
We have used it several years ago without any problems on very low hardware.
But we have very low traffic, about 1M messages/day.

Comment: Thanks. Kannel seemed the best option to me as well, but do you know if it can be used with any sprint devices in particular? What kind of hardware did you have it set up with?

Comment: we was used direct connection to cellular telecom, not by using sms hardware.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Are there any resources out there on this? How can it be done and is it expensive?

Comment: It a cheaper than just send from phone adapter. Also, you should check for collector companies, that have direct connections with large number of cellular telecoms, and can provide you with very cheap plan to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a Windows Software called [Message Master](http://www.derdack.com/index.php?article_id=51&clang=0) for SMS MT/MO with multiple carriers around the world. The Software an handle all major SMSC protocols like CIMD2/SMPP/... and also standard modems. As hardware we are using modems from wavecom for various SIM cards and carriers around the globe.

In addition we are diving deeper and deeper into the above mentioned [kannel](http://www.kannel.org) and it looks like it's able to solve our demand for a fraction of the cost.